# How to use ARRAYFORMULA with this formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to make an array formula which sums up all the rows until this
row.

```
=IF(((M6*0,2)+(N6*0,3)+(O6*0,5))/10=0;"";((M6*0,2)+(N6*0,3)+(O6*0,5))/10)
```

Comment: We can't see your spreadsheet, so we don't know what is in any of your rows. We don't know your layout, data, data types, or end goal. Please share a link to the sheet (or to a copy of it), clearly showing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.